# Image recognition - dice in an image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, image-recognition, dice

I'm developing a WPF application where I need to "find" / "read" dice from an image file (e.g. taken by my webcam) / BitmapSource.

So I need to know the amount of dice found (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6?) and their numbers ...

I've searched on google, but I wasn't able of finding an approach ... The only thing I could find so far is EmGu (a .NET wrapper for the Intel OpenCV image-processing library). However, this seems to be very extensive.

Some further information / thoughts / experiences would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**: to do this task you need a vision library (like OpenCV), there is no way around. Else you would have to implement the needed image processing by yourself.

**Second**: depending on the environment where you capture the image the task can be really hard to do for a machine. For machine vision it is recommended that the image matches the following conditions:

- grey-value
- smooth and dark background
- few objects in the foreground
- object-to-recognize with good contrast to the background

**Third**: to accomplish the task using machine vision here is a small guideline. As ever there are multiple ways to do it.

a) using Binarization

1. filtering: apply a filter e.g. median filter
2. binarization: binarize the image and select the areas of the dice
3. morphology: apply morphological operations (e.g. opening) to get rid of selected but not wanted background parts
4. counting: count the areas with similar features (width,..) like a dice
5. counting: count the holes in the previously selected dice areas

b) machine learning

If you dare, you also can try a machine learning appraoch, using e.g. TensorFlow from Google. In this case you dont have most of the restrictions mentioned above, but instead you need to teach the algorithm with hundreds of images. The images need to be sorted/tagged correctly ("no.1",..). If teached correctly it also would recognize different dice types (size, color, ..) which would be hard to do with way a).

Comment: Thank you, that helps! I'll start with approach a) and with recognizing just 1 die ... I know that it is a hard task and that I won't get a 100% perfectly working solution, but that's not the point, I want to start learning this topic and therefore your information is super!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about image recognition and I think it'd probably be way simpler to just use a dice roller program.
I know AI is hard. Very hard.
Probably the easiest approach with AI here would be one where you teach the AI spot count and dice count.

Say you have the web cam overhead and arrange that the only white things in the picture are spots.
You could take a picture and then "just" iterate through it checking for white in the image using xy co-ordinates in the picture. 
When you find one then any connected white is still that spot.
Any un-connected white is another spot.
You will want to tune this process so shiny bits or whatever don't get picked up. 
If the dice are not green and you roll on green baize then similarly when you hit not-green then that's a dice.